# @if (Auth::user() == $image->user_id) doesn't work even though logged user has id of 1 and $image->user_id has id 1 as well

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to display the delete image button only if the logged user is the one who has uploaded the image. Unfortunately, when I do that, the delete image button disappears even though the logged user is the creator of the images. I do not see why would that not work correctly.

```
<div class="wrapper">
        <div class='imageContainer'>
            <h1 class='imageTitle'>{{$image->name}}</h1>
            <div class="stickyImageContainer">
                <img class='uploadedRealImage' src='/storage/images/uploaded/{{$image->file_name}}' alt='Random image'/>
                @if (Auth::user() == $image->user_id)
                    <div class='deleteImageButton'></div>
                    <a class='deleteImageA' href='{{ route('deleteImage', ['image_id' => $image->id]) }}'>X</a>
                @endif
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're trying to compare User object with integer. So, change it to:

```
@if (Auth::id() === $image->user_id)
```

Also, you should use [policies](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/authorization#generating-policies) for this:

```
@can('delete', $image)
```

Comment: This worked fine. Strangely, the Laravel 5.2 tutorial I'm following did it by using @if (Auth::user() == $image->user_id) and it worked just fine.